# Adding fading animation to slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have the following code that creates a slideshow with these images, but I cant seem to be able to add a fade in-out animation for the images, so the transition is just jarring. Is there any simple way to fade transition?

```
var i = 0;
    var images = [];
    var slideTime = 3000; // 3 seconds
    
    images[0] = 'one.jpg';
    images[1] = 'two.jpg';
    images[2] = 'six.jpg';
    
    function changePicture() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
    
        if (i < images.length - 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(changePicture, slideTime);
    }
    
    window.onload = changePicture;
    
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place `<div>`s one over the other and play with their opacities. But why invent the wheel? use a slider plugin.

```js
$('.your-class').slick({
  fade: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="your-class">
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/337/200"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well thanks, you're right. I was just making things hard for myself.